# 404 Page Not Found con codeigniter haciendo validación

Tags: php, codeigniter, validación

estoy haciendo un ejercicio luego de haber visto un tutorial, la idea es validar un formulario. Pero al ejecutarlo así:
http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/formulario_cliente

Me devuelve 404 Page Not Found

El controlador cliente.php

```
<?php
class cliente extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }


    function mostrarDatos(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texDocumentoDeIdentidad', 'Documento de identidad', 'trim|required|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texPassword', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texNombre', 'Nombre', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texApellido', 'Apellido', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texDireccion', 'Dirección', 'trim|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texTelefono', 'Teléfono', 'trim|min_length[7]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texFechaIngreso', 'Fecha de ingreso', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('texEstado', 'Estado', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[16]');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('formulario_cliente');
        }
        else{

            $datos=array(
                'documentoDeIdentidad' => $this->input->post('texDocumentoDeIdentidad'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('texPassword'),
                'nombre' => $this->input->post('texNombre'),
                'apellido' => $this->input->post('texApellido'),
                'direccion' => $this->input->post('texDireccion'),
                'telefono' => $this->input->post('texTelefono'),
                'fechaIngreso' => $this->input->post('texFechaIngreso'),
                'estado' => $this->input->post('texEstado')                 
            );
            $this->load->view("formulario_cliente", $datos);
        }
    }


}
```

?>

La vista formulario_cliente.php

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <TITLE></TITLE>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">         
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/estilos.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="cliente.php">Cliente </a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="cuentaxcliente.php">Cuenta Cliente</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="transaccuenta.php">Transac Cuenta</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="tipotransaccion.php">Tipo de Transacción</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <h2 align='center'>Cliente</h2> 

    <div id="error">
        <?php 
            echo validation_errors();
        ?>
    </div>
    <br>

    <?php
        echo form_open('cliente/mostrarDatos');
    ?>
    Documento de identidad
    <input type="text" name="texDocumentoDeIdentidad" id="texDocumentoDeIdentidad" value="<?php echo set_value('texDocumentoDeIdentidad', '');?>"/> 
    <br>
    Password
    <input type="text" name="texPassword" id="texPassword" />
    <br>
    Nombres
    <input type="text" name="texNombres" id="texNombres" value="<?php echo set_value('texNombres', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Apellidos
    <input type="text" name="texApellidos" id="texApellidos" value="<?php echo set_value('texApellidos', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Dirección
    <input type="text" name="texDireccion" id="texDireccion" value="<?php echo set_value('texDireccion', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Teléfono
    <input type="text" name="texTelefono" id="texTelefono" value="<?php echo set_value('texTelefono', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Fecha de ingreso
    <input type="text" name="texFechaDeIngreso" id="texFechaDeIngreso" value="<?php echo set_value('texFechaDeIngreso', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Estado
    <input type="text" name="texEstado" id="texEstado" value="<?php echo set_value('texEstado', '');?>"/>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="buscarCliente" value="Buscar Cliente" />
    <input type="reset" name="limpiar" value="Limpiar" />   

    <?php
        echo form_close();
    ?>

    <br>    
    <div id="resultado">
        <?php
            if(!empty($documentoDeIdentidad) && !empty($password) && !empty($nombre) && !empty($apellido) && !empty($fechaIngreso) && !empty($estado)){

                echo "Documento de identidad: $documentoDeIdentidad<br>";
                echo "Password: $password<br>";
                echo "Nombre: $nombre<br>";
                echo "Apellido: $apellido<br>";
                echo "Dirección: $direccion<br>";
                echo "Teléfono: $telefono<br>";
                echo "Fecha de ingreso: $fechaIngreso<br>";
                echo "Estado: $estado<br>";             
            }
        ?>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

En el config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter';
```

En routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'cliente';
```

Comment: no existe la página, puedes acceder a http://localhost/ ? puedes usar la ip de tu pc en lugar de "localhost".

Comment: Con localhost puedo acceder a otro programa que tengo.

Comment: Ok entonces revisa si la url es correcta http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/formulario_cliente @JhonHernández

Comment: Sí, la url es la correcta. Intenté con la ip del equipo y sigue dando 404

Comment: Faltaba el nombre de la función mostrarDatos en la url: http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/mostrarDatos/formulario_cliente

Comment: En realidad la url no existía, por eso el error 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que comentas:

> 404 error page not found

indica en español:

> Error 404 Página no encontrada

Esto sucede cuando el servidor Web recibe la solicitud de la URL pero esta no puede ser localizada. Si el servidor funciona como lo comentas ya que puedes acceder a otros recursos mediante http://localhost/ entonces seguramente la página que tratas de cargar en realidad no se encuentra

```
http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/formulario_cliente
```

al final la URL no era la correcta por lo tanto no se encotraba el recurso, el url como ahora comentas en realidad era:

```
http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/mostrarDatos/formulario_cliente
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, no tienes un método o función llamada formulario_cliente entonces al ejecutar tu url te fallará
http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/formulario_cliente

Lo que puedes hacer para que funcione la url anterior es o bien cambias el nombre del método en cliente.php de

```
function mostrarDatos(){
```

a

```
function formulario_cliente(){
```

o bien

```
$route['cliente/formulario_cliente'] = 'cliente/mostrarDatos';
```